# a close button replace toggle class - isotope

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've asked a similar question but still wanted to know Why I am unable to remove `selected`
I think this is right action to remove `selected` class

```
$(this).parents('.item').removeClass('selected');
```

online sample http://jsfiddle.net/QxdXW/

HTML

```
<div class="item"><div class="close">X</div></div>
```

jQuery

```
var $close = $('.close');

$close.click(function(){
var $this = $(this);
   $(this).parents('.item').removeClass('selected');

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use **[e.stopPropagation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/)** to prevent your click event bubble up from `.close` to parent `.item` div which will trigger your div to add class `selected` again:

```
$close.click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    var $this = $(this);
    $(this).parents('.item').removeClass('selected');
});
```

---

Also, you need to close your `<div id="container">` using `</div>` not `</p>`

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QxdXW/16/)**

Comment: Awesome! trying to figure out why I was unable to trigger it. thanks a lot for your answer

Comment: also, closing tag of div is p mention that

Comment: @Felix Will tick it once after timer unlocked